# After I do "ionic platform add android" ,I can't find new folder in my Project.likes 'yourProject/platforms/android' no android.;

Tags: ionic-framework

After I do "ionic platform add android" ,I can't find new folder in my Project.likes 'yourProject/platforms/android' no android.;

[image: command line]

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command with sudo. By the way when you create the project the ionic framework automatically adds the ios platform. If sudo doesn't work try to reinstall ionic, may be there is something wrong with it.